# Get top 4 biggest values from each column using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, subset

I have a two columns which show the sentiment analysis for positive and negative scores. Here's the output:

```
scat=btweet[['sentiment_pos', 'sentiment_negative']]
scat

sentiment_pos    sentiment_negative

0.286              0.000
0.451              0.000
0.143              0.300
0.151              0.100
```

I want to get top biggest values from each column,
I tried to that, But only got the biggest value for one column.

```
scat.nlargest(4, 'sentiment_pos')

 sentiment_pos    sentiment_negative

    0.451             0.000
    0.286             0.000
    0.151             0.300
    0.143             0.100
```

My output should be like this

```
  sentiment_pos    sentiment_negative

    0.451             0.300
    0.286             0.100
    0.151             0.000
    0.143             0.000
```

Can anyone help me write the code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorise this calculation via `numpy`.

For example, for the 2 largest in each column:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=0)[::-1][:2], columns=df.columns)
```

Result:

```
   sentiment_pos  sentiment_negative
0          0.451                 0.3
1          0.286                 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function that. It takes *n*-number of max values in each column in the dataframe

```
    def TopMaxValues(n):

        sentiment_pos = []
        sentiment_negative=[]

        arrsentiment_pos=np.array(sentimentdf['sentiment_pos'])
        arrsentiment_negative=np.array(sentimentdf['sentiment_negative'])
        idx1 = list((-arrsentiment_pos).argsort()[:n])
        idx2 = list((-arrsentiment_negative).argsort()[:n])

        for MaxValue in range(len(idx1)):
            sentiment_pos.append(sentimentdf['sentiment_pos'][idx1[MaxValue]])
            sentiment_negative.append(sentimentdf['sentiment_negative'][idx2[MaxValue]])

        sentimentdf['sentiment_pos']=sentiment_pos
        sentimentdf['sentiment_negative']=sentiment_negative    

        return resultsdf
```